# Returning laravel realtionship within json

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.7

I am currently doing this as title says like this:

```
$user = User::where('username', request('username'))->first();

$posts = [];
$comments = [];
foreach($user->posts as $post){
 foreach($post->comments as $comment){
  array_push($comments, [
    'id' => $comment->id,
    'body' => $comment->body,
    'user' => $comment->user->only(['name', 'id']),
  ]);
 }
  array_push($posts, [
    'title' => $post->title,
    'id' => $post->id,
    'body' => $post->body,
    'comments' => $comments,
  ]);
}
return response()->json([
  'user' => $user->only(['name', 'avatar', 'age']),
  'posts' => $posts,
]);
```

Is there a shorter way of doing this like:

```
$user->only(['name', 'avatar', 'age'])->withPostsOnly(['id', 'title', 'body'])->withCommentsOnly(['id', 'body']);
```

I know there is a way to make methods inside models that return these parts of data and then to use it same as above but shorter.

But is there any way to use something like `getNameAttribute($value)` for relations so I can say:

`$user->only(['id', 'name', 'age', 'posts'])`;

And in posts value I need to have all posts and relationship data like comments and users that are connected to comments.

So basically in User model:

```
public function posts() {
  return $this->hasMany('App/Post')->only('id', 'title', 'body', 'comments');
}
```

And inside Post model:

```
public function comments() {
  return $this->hasMany('App/Comment')->only('id', 'body', 'user');
}
```

And inside Comment model:

```
public function comments() {
  return $this->belongsTo('App/User')->only('id', 'name');
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Better use firstOrFail or check to see if a user is returned to avoid fatal errors for invalid usernames.

Comment: Okay I will, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably overcomplicating it to be honest.

```
$user = User::where('username', request('username'))->first();
$user->load(['posts.comments']);
return response()->json($user);
```

This is a simplified version maybe but still should indicate you can just load relationships on models.

Comment: Give me some explanation here: `$user->load(['posts', 'comments']);` are comments in relation with user or with posts

Comment: my bad, will edit how you load a relationship of a relationship

Comment: Why not `User::with(["posts.comments"])->where(...)->first();`? What's the logic to split that into 2 db calls instead of one?

Comment: So `$user->load(['posts.comments']);` returns posts and comments for each post? So `posts.comments.user` should return posts with comments with user that is connected to comment?

Comment: @Learner Yes, but you have to define those relationships too

Comment: Just a bit more efficient. For a single record, this isn't too big an issue, but say in a loop, this would tank your database connection :P

Comment: I found out one more thing I forgot to mention, how can I paginate these xD ?

I am using `$user->post()->paginate(10)` and then `$post->comments()->paginate(10)`, is there a way to return paginated relationship? :D

Comment: @TimLewis I found out 
`$post->setRelation('relationName', $post->comments()->paginate(10));` but is there a way to declare custom relation method inside model so I can access it with `load(['posts.relationName'])` ?

Comment: Not that I'm familiar with. Paginating relationships is a pretty complicated thing, and somewhat separate from the original issue you opened. I would consider opening a new question for that, and also consider marking this as accepted. Best to keep questions on SO focused on a single issue.

Comment: Okay I will post new question :D